# My ex-employer was recently acquired and wants me back on board - what should I do?

Tags: career-development, job-change, job-offer, acquisition

I left my ex-employer (of 2 years), largely because of future uncertainty (didn't raise funding) when I was going through some big life changes.  Additionally, my old company was notorious for not giving raises and having minimal benefits.  That being said, I genuinely loved my job and the office social life was pretty awesome.  My new position (~4 months) is a developer position, which I thought would be a step in the right direction for a more technical career.  Additionally, it came with a massive raise and good benefits.

At the time, it seemed my new position would be great, but it is seeming like it is just as unstable as the last (no leadership, never made a release on time, up for a major review they did not disclose) and full of tasks that I dislike that were not in my job description (QA and repetitive manual tasks, not development).

Recently my ex-employer was acquired by another company that is going for their first few rounds of funding and has decided they want me to come back.  There has been a big leadership change, so could be good or could be a mixed bag.  All in all, the offer is around my current salary, without some of the benefits of my current position.

Should I treat the offer as toxic?  Or, since my reasons for leaving were not primarily financial, should I seriously consider going back?

Comment: I don't think anyone but you can answer this question. Watch this Ted talk - I think it will help you: http://www.ted.com/talks/ruth_chang_how_to_make_hard_choices

Comment: If you left on good terms, why would you suspect the previous job's offer of being a problem?  Is it just the loss of benefits, or do you have other reasons to hesitate?  (And if you didn't leave on good terms, what happened?)

Comment: New leadership means new company, evaluate the offer as you would any other offer. Much of what you liked the first time may no lnger be there.   Ask questions to find out waht has changed and why.

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695

Answer (score 4):

I'd say "Keep your powder dry". Don't commit to anything just yet:

1. You could pay the office a visit and make some kind of eyeball assessment as to whether things have changed and by how much. Chat up the current management during your office visit.
2. Try to find colleagues who elected to stay when you elected to leave, get their contact info and talk to them one on one during the off-hours. They're the ones who are best placed to recommend the firm to you as a good place to work

Make your own assessment as to whether you want to come back, after you've got your feedback and gone over it.

Comment: I can't endorse point #2 strongly enough. You spent two years there and say the social life was awesome - I assume you're still in touch with people who work there, if you've only been gone 4 months? Pick their brains!!

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but isn't the phrase "Keep your *powder* dry"?

Comment: @Bobson It must have been a Freudian slip on my part - Thanks for looking out for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make the decision that is right for your career.  Based on what you've written here, I don't know if you have sufficient information to make such a determination.

You loved your old job, but you moved so that you would have a more technical job.  This is an excellent reason to move.  Is the position at the newly-acquired company a technical position?  What changes has the acquisition brought, such as organizational changes, changes to the roadmap, changes to deadlines, etc?  Is the newly-acquired company as great as the pre-acquired company?  If it is, will it continue to be?  If you still have friends at the company, this is an excellent time to meet up with them for coffee or lunch and see what they think about it.  If you don't still have friends at the company, that fact might answer your questions.

Speaking as someone who has been a software engineer for quite some time, you seem to have some assumptions about development that aren't accurate, and might be negatively impacting your assessment of your current position.  Most projects of any appreciable size miss either their deadlines or items on their feature lists, and often both.  Anyone who has been a developer for any length of time can tell you about the feature that they thought would take a week, and somehow ended up taking six months.  Depending on the organization of the company, reviews can either be something that they don't mention because they don't think of as major milestones, or they can be major milestones that only get scheduled when the team is ready for a review.  Likewise, there's often a lot of repetitive work in development, and QA and development go hand-in-hand.  It's also common for the most junior developers to get easier tasks which might not be the most interesting ones, to help them get up-to-speed on the codebase and to ensure that they're a good technical fit for the development work that needs to be done.  For example, someone who's a great backend database developer is not necessarily also a great user experience developer.  Before deciding that you are doing work that is out-of-scope for a developer, consider discussing your duties in current role with more experienced developers or your manager to get their perspective.  With this in mind, you should reassess whether your current role is really as bad as you think it is.